# wx.grid.Grid How to not change background colour of cell when you select one row

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Below is a sample of wx.grid.Grid, this grid's selection mode is by "wx.grid.Grid.SelectRows". I set background color for every cell on column1, when I select row1, the selection colour will cover the cell background colour which I set before. Any possible when I select the row, selection colour don't change the cell background colour on column1.

```
import wx, wx.grid
class example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent,id=-1,size=(330,150),title='example')
        panel=wx.Panel(self,-1)
        grid_window=wx.grid.Grid(panel,id=-1,size=(320,270))
        grid_window.CreateGrid(3,3,wx.grid.Grid.SelectRows)
        grid_window.SetCellHighlightROPenWidth(0)
        grid_window.SetColLabelValue(0,'Column1')
        grid_window.SetColLabelValue(1,'Column2')
        grid_window.SetColLabelValue(2,'Column3')

        grid_window.SetCellValue(0,0,'10')
        grid_window.SetCellValue(0,1,'A')
        grid_window.SetCellValue(0,2,'a')
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(0,0,True)
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(0,1,True)
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(0,2,True)
        grid_window.SetCellBackgroundColour(0,0,'blue')

        grid_window.SetCellValue(1,0,'20')
        grid_window.SetCellValue(1,1,'B')
        grid_window.SetCellValue(1,2,'b')
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(1,0,True)
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(1,1,True)
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(1,2,True)
        grid_window.SetCellBackgroundColour(1,0,'green')

        grid_window.SetCellValue(2,0,'30')
        grid_window.SetCellValue(2,1,'C')
        grid_window.SetCellValue(2,2,'c')
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(2,0,True)
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(2,1,True)
        grid_window.SetReadOnly(2,2,True)
        grid_window.SetCellBackgroundColour(2,0,'Yellow')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame =example(None,-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpFpp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC4A9.png)

Comment: The selection colour will be part of the system `Theme`, not `wxPython`.

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to happen: do you still want the other cells in the row to appear selected, but not the cell in the first column? If so, IMO this would look very weird. But perhaps you want to achieve something else? Please explain what is it in this case.

Comment: I want the other cells in the row to appear selected, but not the first column.

Comment: Another case I thought:  whole row to appear selected, and the cell of first column still show its own background colour.

Comment: the purpose is the colour means the curve line colour I show in matplotlib, when I select the row, it show first column colour line in plot.

Comment: @TaoYe, Did you try `SetCellBackgroundColour()`?

Comment: @logr, I tried SetCellBackgroundColour() but it doesn't work.

Comment: @TaoYe, which event are you processing? How do you bind the handler? can you show the event code?

Comment: How do you think your user will understand whether the cell is selected or not if you dont change the background color?

Comment: @macroland, because 2nd and 3rd columns' background colour is changed to selected colour.

Comment: @lgor  handler is bind with: grid_window.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT, self.plot_selected_line_curves)

Comment: @TaoYe, why not use ` wxGridSelectCells`?

Comment: Or try to bind to `EVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_CLICK` and change the color there.